# loop over a function phi(x,y,r) in python

Tags: python, loops

I create a function phi(x,y) that allows me to get a circular level set. This function works and the plot works too.
Now, I am trying to keep the same function that create multiple circular level set. Basically, it should be done through a loop, I think I have mistakes in my looping code.

Before creating the loop:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
xstart, xend = 0.0, 8.0
ystart, yend = 0.0, 8.0
N = 50
x = numpy.linspace(xstart,xend, N)
y = numpy.linspace(ystart,yend, N)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)
x_center , y_center = 3.0, 4.0
radius = 0.7
phi = numpy.sqrt((X-x_center)**2+(Y-y_center)**2)-radius
pyplot.contour(X, Y, phi, levels = [0])
```

The loop that I tried to make, first I tried with:

```
x_center = [ 3, 6, 7, 2]
y_center = [4, 6, 2, 1]
radius = [0.7, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1]

for i in enumerate(x_center):
    for j in enumerate(y_center):
        for k in enumerate(radius):
            phi[i,j,k] = numpy.sqrt((X-x_center[i])**2 + (Y-y_center[j])**2) - radius[k]
        
            pyplot.contour(X, Y, phi[i,j], levels =[0])
```

I also tried:

```
for i in range(len(radius)):
    x_c = x_center[i]
    y_c = y_center[i]
    r   = radius[i]
    phi[i] = (numpy.sqrt((X-x_c)**2+(Y-y_c)**2)-r)
```

I think I am making some mistakes. Does anyone knows the correct way to create a loop for phi, looping over different radius and different centers coordinates?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the question what you expect to get from the code.

If the following code is used:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
xstart, xend = 0.0, 8.0
ystart, yend = 0.0, 8.0

N = 50
x = numpy.linspace(xstart,xend, N)
y = numpy.linspace(ystart,yend, N)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)

x_center = [ 3, 6, 7, 2]
y_center = [4, 6, 2, 1]
radius = [0.7, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1]

for i in range(len(x_center)):
    for j in range(len(y_center)):
        for k in range(len(radius)):        
            pyplot.contour(X, Y, numpy.sqrt((X-x_center[i])**2 + (Y-y_center[j])**2) - radius[k], levels=0)

pyplot.show()
```

It generates:
[image]

Changing `N` to a higher value, say `N = 500`, will create smoother circles:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had just figure it out.
I think I need to loop over only i:

Comment: for i in range(len(x_center)):
    pyplot.contour(X, Y, numpy.sqrt((X-x_center[i])**2 + (Y-y_center[i])**2) - radius [i], levels = [0])

pyplot.show()